# Meson: connect two strings without '/'

Tags: meson-build

I want to concatenate two strings without a separator between them (so no new destination).

```py
theme_dir_dark = join_paths(get_option('datadir'), 'themes', meson.project_name(), '-dark')
```

`meson.project_name()` is Pop and I want `theme_dir_dark` to end with `Pop-dark` and not `Pop/-dark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either with formatting or concatenation `'@0@-dark'.format(meson.project_name())` or `meson.project_version() + '-dark'`

Comment: Nice thanks! `meson.project_version() + '-dark'` did it for me.